# 403 Error Missing Scopes writing to Google Sheets with Python

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to connect my Python script to upload the output to a `GSpread`. I'm getting **403 Errors** in my response:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/root?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

MyCode is as below:

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('xx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx.json', scope)


spreadsheet_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks_name = 'Sheet1'

d2g.upload(predictions,spreadsheet_key,wks_name,credentials = credentials)
```

I'm pretty new to Python so I'm learning by doing, but can't fathom this for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For example, how about adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) I posted this as a comment because I'm not sure about your whole situation. If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yes adding the Drive APIs access worked

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to add access to Drive as well as spreadsheets

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```